# Some of my links won't interact when i press them

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I made this site for a school assignment and it all went flawless until.. *this happened*. I try to hover over the **Home** and **News** button in the navigation bar but it does not work and nothing seems to happen when i try to press on them, the **Contacts** and the **About** button seem to work fine, though.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("https://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/4550942/thumb/1.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.title {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ad8961;
  width: 70%;
  height: calc(15vh);
  font-size: calc(10vh);
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow';
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 0.6%;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #04406d;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.home {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: -87%;
  top: 25%;
}

.news {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: -66%;
  top: -17%;
}

.contacts {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: -41%;
  top: -60%;
}

.about {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: 90%;
  top: -104%;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ad8961;
  width: 70%;
  height: calc(76.5vh);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -1.7%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.boxtext {
  background: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

a:link {
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Sample Text</div>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></div>
  <div class="news"><a href="#news">News</a></div>
  <div class="contacts"><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></div>
  <div class="about"><a href="#about">About</a></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxtext">
    <h1><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></h1>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: this is not a proper way to make elements side by side. You are forcing block element to be side by side using negative margin and at the end they will overlap. You may read about inline-block, float, flexbox, etc

Comment: The simple way is by using ul and li then set all your li to float left.  Position property will not fill up the space the element is placed. Therefore other elements will be overlapping each other.